# HttpWebRequest to web-service in c#; how to get data FAST from the response stream?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, web-services, stream

I am calling a web-service with POST and receiving a 2MB xml.
The problem is that it takes to much time until i can use the data within the Stream.
The response seems to be after 7 secs there, but it takes another 10 sec to read the content(its a string) from response stream.

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(MyUri);
req.Method = "POST";

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = Poststring.Length;
s.Start();
StreamWriter swriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
swriter.Write(Poststring);
swriter.Close();

// Get the response. 7 sec
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
s.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Talking to Web-Service: "+s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

s.Reset(); 
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.  10 sec
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(dataStream);
s.Start();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
s.Stop(); 
Debug.WriteLine("Convert stream to some useful data: "+s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

output in milliseconds

```
Talking to Web-Service: 6595
"Convert" stream to some useful data: 10772
```

Why does it take like 10 sec to read the content??
Is there stil some communication with the web-service or waiting for data when content is read? Its just a simple textfile (xml) with about 2MB. I thought that those 2 MB were transfered within the 6596 milliseconds. Because when i call that service with  my browser, the xml content is shown in 6-7 sec.

The time for Talking to Web-Service is ok, but what is going on in those 10772 milliseconds?

**Edit:** The problem is stil there. I get different answers and they **contradict** each other.

Comment: What kind of service is this? ASMX or WCF?

Comment: What is the endpoint configuration of the service?  What bindings?

Comment: thats the problem. i do not know the details. Its done with django python and i send key=value(Poststring) pair.   swriter.Write(Poststring);

Comment: How long does the XML file take to parse in a test app just reading it from file?  (If the parse is complicated it might take longer than you'd expect.)

Comment: if i read the same xmlFile from my hdd, it takes 15-20 Milliseconds. I also already read the file from a fileStream into a memorytream. XDocument xdoc=Xdocument.Load(memorystream) 30 Milliseconds.... its a standard xml file, BUT with 1 complicated value. There is one Value from a tag with like 15-20k Characters. <tagXY>1StringWith15000Characters</tagXY>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

resulting in:

```
Talking to Web-Service: 6595
"Convert" stream to some useful data: 256
```

Now i have the same performance like in a browser!

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream(), LoadOptions.None);
```

Avoid the XmlReader.Create and use the XDocument.Load(Stream, LoadOptions) overload.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838321.aspx

Comment: thx, I have already tryed that, but its the same thing. u need .net 4.0

Comment: @Gero - Try using WebClient.DownloadString and XDocument.Parse, this might circumvent the odd slowdown on the XDocument.Load

Answer (score 0):

`GetResponse` will not return the full response stream. `GetResponse` will send your request and return an `HttpWebResponse` object based on the header information from the response. `HttpWebResponse` also has an associated stream from which you can read the full response body. This is precisely what you are doing.

I suspect that the 7-second delay you are seeing when you call `GetResponse` is a delay on the server in generating the XML document and sending a response. The further 10-second delay on `XmlReader.Create` is from reading the response stream (ie, downloading the file).

Is the XML generated dynamically? 7 seconds is not a terribly long time for an HTTP response, depending of course on your server location, quality, etc.

Comment: you are right with your first paragraph. But when i perform the same query to the web-service from a website, with an interface issued also as HTTP POST, it takes only 7 sec and the browser shows the xml file(content) in a window.

Comment: Hmmm that's very interesting. I'm confused too now :P

Comment: i think `GetResponse` gets you all the data. The missing of "gzip,deflate" was the problem.