# Downloading with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Lets say that I use `HttpWebRequest` to call a web-service written in python and that service returns a XML file. Lets assume that it takes 10 seconds to download the data.

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

 if(allDate100%Transfered)
 MsgBox.show("u can now CUT your cable. All data is there!!!");
```

Are there any property to check if everything have been transferred?

Because I want to proceed and for example read the received data into a string, but only when all data have been downloaded successfully.

```
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
String xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Do I get any message or sign from the webservice, which tells me that all data is really there and I do not need the connection anymore?

**Edit:** The problem is stil there. I get different answers and they **contradict** each other.

Comment: Spend some more time on formatting and on your English. Use **bold** instead of capitals and avoid exclamation marks. Shouldn't your code say `response.GetResponseStream()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.GetResponse()` is synchronous which means that it doesn't return until all data have been downloaded.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx)  of `request.GetResponse()` states that `WebException` is thrown if:

- Abort was previously called.
- The time-out period for the request expired.
- An error occurred while processing the request.

Which means that everything went OK if no exception was thrown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8391670/963546 ; Quote:GetResponse will not return the full response stream. **What is now true?**

Comment: Nothing in the documentation indicates that what the other answer states is true. And I have a hard time believing that the body wont be fetched from the server unless `GetResponseStream` is called.

Comment: Is there any communication between web-service and me, when i call `Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();`?

Comment: Well i assumed the same, but that did not match reality. 
`response.GetResponseStream();` seems to still need connection to web-service. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8390282/963546